# Compile jar to dex using D8 and linux terminal

Tags: android, jar, dex

I'm trying to compile  jar to dex using D8 and linux terminal

D8 in sdk tools, look at screen.

I want to convert MySecretClass.jar to dex file. What commant I should to enter in terminal ubuntu.

D8 and MySecretClass.jar in the same dir

I tried everything to do it

[image]

Comment: See the documentation on D8 here https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/81753fece70e60120bc72c694e6e12f9af76f71e/README.md and https://developer.android.com/tools/d8

Comment: @Robert thank you, but first link contains just 2 strings about d8 and it is doesn't work, the second link contains nothing about Linux, it is only for Windows ((

Comment: The second link documents the d8 command. If you see Windows paths then this might be a bug on Google side because I am on Windows and see Linux commands. But in the end the difference is just `/` or `\ ` as path separator and how to get the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The right command to Linux is:

`java -jar d8.jar --release Secret.jar`

it will build `classes.dex` file in the same directory.